# SendFile in my controller in yii2 app return 0 bytes file, why?

Tags: php, yii2

my action in my controller:

```
public function actionGetFile($id)
    {
        if(($file = Upload::findOne(['id' => $id])) !== NULL){
            // Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type',$file->mime_type);
            // Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Description','File Transfer');
            // Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
            // Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Accept-Ranges', ['bytes']);
            Yii::$app->response->sendFile(
                Site::UPLOADS_DOMAIN . '/' . $file->getFilePath(false),
                $file->original_name . "." . $file->original_extension,
                ['mimeType'=>$file->mime_type, 'inline'=>false]
            );
        }
        else
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The selected file does not exist.');
    }
```

when i do get request on this url: /controller-name/get-file?id=n
and he returns named file but he was empty

Comment: `sendFile` as first arg accept path to file (i.e /var/www/site/.../common.jpg), `Site::UPLOADS_DOMAIN` looks like part of url.

Comment: print path `Site::UPLOADS_DOMAIN . '/' . $file->getFilePath(false)` make sure path and file exists and it has correct permissions

Comment: the path is correct if you just make a get request from this link then the file starts downloading

Comment: and when I access my action, it returns an empty file